# Average values given times and make a pivot table

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have a table like this:

```
time     | sensor | value |
---------------------------
10:00:00 | 1      |  12.3 |
10:00:00 | 2      |  14.3 |
10:00:00 | 3      |  15.3 |
10:00:01 | 1      |  15.3 |
10:00:02 | 2      |  11.3 |
10:00:01 | 3      |  10.3 |
10:00:03 | 1      |   9.3 |
10:00:03 | 2      |  15.3 |
10:00:04 | 3      |  11.3 |
...
10:05:01 | 1      |  15.3 |
10:05:02 | 2      |  11.3 |
10:05:01 | 3      |  10.3 |
10:05:03 | 1      |   9.3 |
10:05:03 | 2      |  15.3 |
10:05:04 | 3      |  11.3 |
```

And I need a `Pivot` table where the measurements are averaged in time intervals of lets say one minute, and ordered by sensor:

```
time     | sensor 1| sensor 2| sensor 3|
----------------------------------------
10:00:00 |   11    |    12   |    10   |
10:01:00 |   10    |    13   |    15   |
...
```

I learned how to do this in `MySQL`, but now I am forced to use `SQL Server` and apparently this is completely different to `MySQL`.

Any help is appreciated, also some non trivial tutorial on this would be helpful.

EDIT

Attempt after the reply from Giorgi Nakeuri:

```
DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT STUFF((SELECT '],[' + CAST([Group] AS VARCHAR(10)) FROM tblGroups
GROUP BY [Group]
FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') + ']'

DECLARE @s VARCHAR(MAX) = 'with cte as(
    SELECT tblData.Timestmp, tblSeries.GroupID as SensorID, tblData.SeriesID, tblData.DataValue
    FROM tblData 
    INNER JOIN tblSeries ON tblData.SeriesID = tblSeries.SeriesID

    WHERE (tblSeries.[SeriesName] = ' + 'ActivePower' 
            + 'AND tblData.Timestmp > ' + '2015-02-05 00:00:00' + ' AND  tblData.Timestmp < ' + '2015-02-05 23:59:59'
            + 'AND tblData.DataValue>100)
)
select * from cte
pivot(AVG(DataValue) for GroupID in(' + @cols + ' )) p'


EXEC(@s)
```

The result is:

```
[150],[151],[152],[154],[159],[160],[164],[165],[166],[167],[168],[169],[171],[172],[173],[174],[175],[176],[180],[181],[182],[184],[185],[186],[187],[188],[189],[191],[192],[193],[194],[195],[196],[197],[20],[201],[205],[206],[207],[208],[209],[21],[210],[217],[218],[219],[220],[221],[222],[223],[224],[225],[226],[227],[228],[229],[231],[232],[233],[236],[237],[249],[251],[252],[253],[254],[258],[259],[260],[262],[263],[276],[277],[278],[279],[281],[288],[289],[290],[291],[293],[294],[295],[296],[300],[301],[302],[304],[308],[309],[314],[315],[316],[317],[324],[326],[329],[330],[331],[332],[333],[334],[335],[339],[340],[344],[347],[348],[351],[352],[353],[354],[355],[356],[357],[359],[370],[372],[373],[374],[375],[376],[380],[381],[382],[383],[384],[385],[386],[387],[388],[389],[390],[394],[395],[396],[397],[398],[400],[404],[405],[406],[407],[408],[409],[410],[411],[412],[413],[414],[418],[419],[420],[421],[425],[432],[435],[436],[437],[438],[439],[443],[444],[445],[452],[453],[457],[465],[466],[467],[468],[484],[485],[486],[487],[494],[495],[498],[499],[501],[506],[507],[511],[515],[516],[520],[521],[523],[527],[530],[531],[532],[533],[548],[550],[601],[605],[614],[615],[617],[81],[82],[829]
```

This are the sensor ID's, but not the Pivot table...

Comment: Try this  `+ 'AND tblData.Timestmp > ''2015-02-05 00:00:00'' AND  tblData.Timestmp < ''2015-02-05 23:59:59'''`

Comment: Also change this to `'tblSeries.[SeriesName] = ''ActivePower'' ' +`

Comment: Instead of `exec(@s)` do `print @s` and see if you constructed query correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * from someTable
pivot(AVG(value) for sensor in([1],[2],[3])) p
```

If you have more columns in your table that you have showed then:

```
with cte as(select time, sensor, value from someTable)
select * from cte
pivot(AVG(value) for sensor in([1],[2],[3])) p
```

Dynamic version:

```
DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(MAX) = '' 

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT '],[' + CAST([Group] AS VARCHAR(10)) FROM tblGroups 
WHERE [Group] <> 'meteo' 
GROUP BY [Group] 
FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') + ']' 

DECLARE @s VARCHAR(MAX) = 'with cte as( 
SELECT DATEADD(mi, datediff(mi, 0, tblData.Timestmp), 0) Timestmp, tblSeries.GroupID as SensorID, tblData.DataValue 
FROM tblData INNER JOIN tblSeries ON tblData.SeriesID = tblSeries.SeriesID 
WHERE tblSeries.[SeriesName] = ' + '''ActivePower''' + ' AND tblData.Timestmp > ''' + '2015-02-05 00:00:00''' + ' 
AND tblData.Timestmp < ' + '''2015-02-05 23:59:59''' + ' AND tblData.DataValue>100 
) 
select * from cte 
pivot(AVG(DataValue) for GroupID in(' + @cols + ' )) p' 

EXEC( @s)
```

Comment: How can I generate the list [1],[2],[3] automatically? Can I just use a Select statement? Because in the real life I have hundreds of sensors

Comment: Do you want to get handreeds of columns?

Comment: Yes, that is no problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have tried this but something is not yet correct.

Comment: @SantiPeñate-Vera, do you have more then those 3 rows shown in your table?

Comment: Yes my table is of several TB, and I have registries for each of the sensor ID's, the initial post was just an example thinking that it would be simpler.

Comment: Thanks, but there are no changes...still the same result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79032/discussion-between-giorgi-nakeuri-and-santi-penate-vera).

Comment: Just take inner query `SELECT tblData.Timestmp, tblSeries.GroupID as SensorID, tblData.SeriesID, tblData.DataValue
    FROM tblData 
    INNER JOIN tblSeries ON tblData.SeriesID = tblSeries.SeriesID

    WHERE (tblSeries.[SeriesName] = ' + 'ActivePower' 
            + 'AND tblData.Timestmp > ' + '2015-02-05 00:00:00' + ' AND  tblData.Timestmp < ' + '2015-02-05 23:59:59'
            + 'AND tblData.DataValue>100` and see if it returns something.

Comment: Same problem. The query by itself (no pivot) runs ok, I only need to Pivotize it. Thanks by the help by the way.